# Is it possible to link personal ad account to business account programmatically in facebook?

Tags: api, facebook-marketing-api

I want to aggregate my clients' ad account into my business account automatically.

The client is already logged in via oauth2 process in my website and grant the permissions, `["ads_read", "ads_management", "manage_pages"]`.

I'm succeeded to request access for the client using the endpoint `POST /<business_id>/client_ad_accounts`.

Request image in the client Ad account setting page:

[image]

And, There is a problem.

I want to accept this request programmatically using the client's ACCESS_TOKEN.

```
POST /act_<client_ad_account_id>/agencies
-d "business=<my_business_id>&access_token=<client_access_token>"
```

But, I have a error message `(#10) Ad account <client_ad_account_id> must be managed by a business account to approve agency access`.

Is it possible to accept this request programmatically? If that's possible, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

self answer: Connect client page to the client's business account and add permission `business_management`. Then, everything works fine.

Comment: it looks like your problem is solved, but I still have this same issue, and I didn't get your point, what do you mean by connect client's page to client's business account? Could you please clarify it more, I will be very Thankful to you.

Comment: @MuhammadZumair
A business account is required for Oauth client account.
And, add the page in the business account settings (business.facebook.com).
This process must be done by client.

Then, request business-to-business api using ```POST /act_<client_ad_account_id>/agencies```.

To summarize, we need to connect a business account of oauth user to our business account.